# Post json.request parameters

Tags: json

I have an project (online flight ticket) and in this project I need a Json method (or whatever) for checking the flight details. I must post a request to the Url as below.
(curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://testapi.xxx.com/rest/flightSearch/YOUR_CODE_HERE -d @request.json)
How can I post the parameters to the url and can get the answer if is there available flights? 
The json format is as below.
}
    "fromAirport": "ESB",
    "toAirport": "IST",
    "fromDate": "2013-02-01",
    "adult": 1
}

Comment: what are you using as server side ?? (php, asp, jsp)

Comment: and your question is ambiguous, make it clear and understandable :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
function PostMyRequest(from, to, date, adult) {
         $(document).ready(function () {

             $.ajax({
                 url: 'http://testapi.xxx.com/rest/flightSearch/YOUR_CODE_HERE',
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 data: { 'fromAirport': from, 'toAirport': to, 'fromDate': date, 'adult': adult },
                 responseType: "json",
                 success: function(data){
                    alert( data );
                 error: OnFail  //call some function if you want
             });
             return false;
         })
     };
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for the usefull and fast answer. I couldn't take the parameters yet but I show the error message. That is also a parameter:) I want to do this from .cs side. Do you have any example for this?

Comment: Sorry, just to be clear... you want to take the error message and do what with it?  You want to do this within a class?

Comment: No no normaly I want to take the parameters true, but I could not do but it was my fault. the web service sent me the error parameters. I can fix it it is not important. yes I want to do this example with a class..